# JS/CSS - Moving letters around their original positions on a page

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-transitions

This is my first question on SO, I hope I'm doing it well.

My goal is to have a "magical rune effect", where each letter of a text "floats around" its original position, as if it was suspended in mid-air on a magic parchment of some sort.

To put it simply, it will be used for a game. I know how to make something "float at random" on a page, like a hot air balloon; but this isn't what I'm trying to do : I want the letters to move around their original position.

So far, I've tried something (you can check my fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/3as4omj2/ ), but I'm running into problems.

*(don't worry about the default font and the ugly aqua background, it's used for positionning)*

```
function float(element, range, speed) {
    var position = $(element).offset(); 
    $(element).attr( 'original_x', position.left);
    $(element).attr( 'original_y', position.top);
    $(element).attr( 'range', range );
    $(element).attr( 'speed', speed );
    drift(element);
}

function drift(element) {
    var max = Number.parseInt($(element).attr('range'));
    var speed = Number.parseInt($(element).attr('speed'));
    var pos_x = Number.parseInt($(element).attr('original_x'));
    var pos_y = Number.parseInt($(element).attr('original_y'));
    var drift_x = max/2 - Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
    var drift_y = max/2 - Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
    var final_x = pos_x + drift_x;
    var final_y = pos_y + drift_y;
    var total_wait = Math.sqrt(drift_x*drift_x+drift_y*drift_y)*speed;
    $(element).animate({
        left : final_x+"px",
        top : final_y+"px"
    }, total_wait, /*"linear",*/ function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            drift(element);  
        }, Math.abs(total_wait-Math.floor(Math.random()*150)));
    });
}

$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  float($("#t"),50, 10);
  float($("#e"),50, 10);
  float($("#s"),50, 10);
  float($("#s"),50, 10);
  float($("#t2"),50, 10);
})
```

Here's my problems and questions so far :

1. I can't line up my letters to form a word (like, "TEST" is seen vertically, I'd love to see it as an horizontal "TEST"); ideally, using spans, so I can dynamically add a word or remove it without creating dozens of elements.
2. The text moves bananas... and I don't seem to be understanding why. :(
3. I'd love to be able to "move the original position" along, so that I can animate the letters further (moving the general text left to right, for example).
4. Ultimately, is there a way to optimize the size of the font to the user's display ?

Can you guys give me some advice ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using CSS3 animation instead, setting custom animation delay for every letter using `:nth-of-type()` selector. To better understand all the animation properties, see this [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp). All the rest is the matter of tweaking `translate` values.

---

If you are determined enough, creating custom `@keyframes` for each letter is also an option.

```css
.runes span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: aqua;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: float;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.runes span:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

.runes span:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

.runes span:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

.runes span:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .7s;
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(8px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, 8px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(5px, 5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="runes">
  <span>T</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>S</span>
  <span>T</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your solution is elegant and simple, I like it very much.

How can I make the displacement random ?

Comment: I don't think making it entirely random is possible with CSS. You can make it appear random though, by adding different `@keyframes`.